Is the Bible anti-Semitic?
It seems the Bible is anti-Semitic or how else do you explain these Bible passages?
God himself wanted to kill all Jews but Moses stopped him:

(Ex 32:9-11) 9 And the LORD said to Moses, I have seen this people,
and behold, they are a stubborn people; 10 and now let my anger be
kindled against them and I will destroy them, but I will make you a
great nation. 11 And Moses prayed to the LORD his God, saying, Why, O
LORD, should your anger be kindled against your people, whom you
brought out of the land of Egypt with great power and with a mighty
hand?

God said Israel is the worst nation of the world:

(Ezek 5:4-9) 4 Then you shall take some of them again and throw them
into the midst of the fire and burn them with fire, and a fire shall
go out from them against the whole house of Israel. 5 Thus says the
Lord GOD: I have set this Jerusalem in the midst of the nations and
the countries around it. 6 And she was rebellious against my judgments
in wickedness more than the nations, and against my statutes more than
the countries that are round about her; for they have rejected my
judgments, and they have not walked in my statutes. 7 Therefore, thus
says the Lord GOD: Because you have rebelled more than the nations
that are around you, because you have not walked in my statutes and
have not done my judgments, yes, not even according to the judgments
of the nations that are around you, 8 therefore, thus says the Lord
GOD: Behold, I also will be against you and will execute judgments in
your midst in the sight of the nations. 9 And I will do to you what I
have not done, and what I will not do again, because of all your
abominations.

God said all the house of Israel have a hard forehead and a stubborn heart:

(Ezek 3:5-7) 5 For you are not sent to a people of foreign speech
and a hard language, but to the house of Israel— 6 not to many peoples
of foreign speech and a hard language, whose words you cannot
understand. Surely, if I sent you to such, they would listen to you. 7
But the house of Israel will not be willing to listen to you, for they
are not willing to listen to me: because all the house of Israel have
a hard forehead and a stubborn heart.

Jesus said the Gentiles are better than the Jews:

(Mt 8:10-12) 10 But when Jesus heard it, he marveled and said to those
who followed, Truly I tell you, not even in Israel have I found such
great faith. 11 But I tell you that many (Gentiles) will come from
east and west and recline at table with Abraham and Isaac and Jacob in
the kingdom of heaven, 12 but the sons of the kingdom (the Jews) will
be thrown out into the outer darkness: there will be weeping and
gnashing of teeth.

Apostle Paul about the Jews:

(1 Thess 2:14-16) 14 the Jews, 15 who killed both the Lord Jesus and the prophets, and
persecuted the church, and displease God and oppose all mankind 16 by
hindering us from speaking to the Gentiles that they might be saved—so
as always to fill up the measure of their sins. But wrath has come
upon them at last!


Are you really suggesting that the Jews would hold as their most sacred and cherished text a document that is antisemitic??

According to Jos 5:13,14 God is neither for, nor against, Israel.

Hi Jlem, this question needs some work to hone in on analysing one particular text or works by one particular author. "the Bible" is a set of 66 different books from different authors, periods and languages, and so this kind of question is simply unanswerable at this scale.

Also, welcome to the site! Please do take the Site Tour and check out the help centre to learn how everything works here.

The OP has listed a number of texts that document the anger of the LORD over Israel's sins.  God did not literally hate Israel - he hated their sinfulness!
There are too many verses that express the repeated idea that Israel was God's chosen and blessed people, or that Israel was "my people", such as Deut 7:8, 2 Sam 3:18, 1 Kings 8:16, 1 Chron 16:13, 2 Chron 6:6, Esther 8:13, Ps 16:3, 31:21, 135:4, Isa 41:8, 44:1, 45:4, 49:7, Jer 2:21, etc, etc.
But more important that all of this, the fact that Israel was chosen by God as His special people did not prevent them sinning as the OP has documented.  However, and this is an important "BUT", God is supremely gracious, kind and forgiving:

Ex 34:6, 7 - Then the LORD passed in front of Moses and called out: “The LORD, the LORD God, is compassionate and gracious, slow to anger, abounding in loving devotion and faithfulness, maintaining loving devotion to a thousand generations, forgiving iniquity, transgression, and sin. Yet He will by no means leave the guilty unpunished; He will visit the iniquity of the fathers on their children and grandchildren to the third and fourth generations.”
Neh 9:17 - They refused to listen and failed to remember the wonders You performed among them. They stiffened their necks and appointed a leader to return them to their bondage in Egypt. But You are a forgiving God, gracious and compassionate, slow to anger and rich in loving devotion, and You did not forsake them.
Ps 86:5 - For You, O Lord, are kind and forgiving, rich in loving devotion to all who call on You.
Ps 86:15 - But You, O Lord, are a compassionate and gracious God, slow to anger, abounding in loving devotion and faithfulness.
Ps 103:8 - The LORD is compassionate and gracious, slow to anger, abounding in loving devotion.
Ps 103:4 - But with You there is forgiveness, so that You may be feared.
Ps 145:8 - The LORD is gracious, and full of compassion; slow to anger, and of great mercy.
Jer 3:12 - But with You there is forgiveness, so that You may be feared.
Hos 14:2 - Bring your confessions and return to the LORD. Say to Him: “Take away all our iniquity and receive us graciously, that we may present the fruit of our lips.
Joel 2:13 - So rend your hearts and not your garments, and return to the LORD your God. For He is gracious and compassionate, slow to anger, abounding in loving devotion. And He relents from sending disaster.
Jonah 4:2 - So he prayed to the LORD, saying, “O LORD, is this not what I said while I was still in my own country? This is why I was so quick to flee toward Tarshish. I knew that You are a gracious and compassionate God, slow to anger, abounding in loving devotion—One who relents from sending disaster.


+1 Exactly.  If the OP logic holds, then the question should have been, "Is God anti-human?"  But, contrary to being anti-human, and completely consistent with your point, there's those two [sarcasm for effect] "insignificant"...details of the incarnation and resurrection of the Christ.   It's not God that is anti.  It's we who are anti-him. But, "Who can separate us from the love of God..." Romans 8:26-39.

I'm really confused as to why so many people are answering a question that's so clearly off topic, rather than VTC. Please help new users to hone their questions so that they can learn the site scope and improve the question to the point that we can answer them exetetically.

(This question is a repost of a closed item in Christianity.SE, so I'll repost my answer too.)
Remember, the Israelites were known as the chosen people.
God chose them to set an example to the world, both as a good example and as a bad example.
Deuteronomy 28 is known as the blessings and curses chapter.
In it God tells the Israelites about the blessings they will receive if they follow his guidance, and about the curses they will receive if they don't.
The verses in the question were selected because they describe instances where Israel didn't follow God's way of life.
It isn't a matter of antisemitism, simply a matter of cherry-picking the data to produce the desired result.
As for the NT selection, it is saying that the Thessalonian Church was persecuted by some non-Christian Thessalonians, just as the Jewish Church was persecuted by some non-Christian Jews.
Read the NLT translation:

2:14 And then, dear brothers and sisters, you suffered persecution from your own countrymen. In this way, you imitated the believers in God’s churches in Judea who, because of their belief in Christ Jesus, suffered from their own people, the Jews.
2:15 For some of the Jews killed the prophets, and some even killed the Lord Jesus. Now they have persecuted us, too. They fail to please God and work against all humanity
2:16 as they try to keep us from preaching the Good News of salvation to the Gentiles. By doing this, they continue to pile up their sins. But the anger of God has caught up with them at last.


I'm really confused as to why so many people are answering a question that's so clearly off topic, rather than VTC. Please help new users to hone their questions so that they can learn the site scope and improve the question to the point that we can answer them exetetically.


How else do you explain these passages?

For starters, we read more than just these passages, and illuminate them together! As others have said, there are plenty of passages that outline the goodness of God, how he shows unmerited favor to the nation of Israel, and the "Jews' " benefits over gentiles. Yes, [some] Jews killed Jesus, killed the prophets, and persecuted the apostles, but it's obvious even from that passage in 1 Thess that these actions were taken by different Jews (i.e. this wasn't a few Jews who all did the evil, nor was it all Jews).
Two passages worth considering for more context:

Romans 9:4-5 "They are Israelites, and to them belong the adoption, the glory, the covenants, the giving of the law, the worship, and the promises. To them belong the patriarchs, and from their race - according to the flesh - is the Christ who is God over all, blessed forever. Amen (ESV)
John 4: 22b "...Salvation is from the Jews" (ESV)

If merely pointing out the sins/failures of [some] Jews makes the Bible "antisemetic", then perhaps a new definition is needed for that term. It's not "antiDavidic" for pointing out David's sins, nor is it "antihumanity" for declaring that we are all dead in our sins and trespasses, enemies of God apart from His grace!
